# rbenv error on newly updated mac os x 10.10.1

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm, rbenv

Hi Im a newbie to ruby and rails and terminal and I updated to mac os x 10.10 yosimite and these errors started popping up when I open up terminal

```
-bash: /Users/marklacsamana/.bash_profile: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/marklacsamana/.bash_profile: line 4: `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/marklacsamana/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/marklacsamana/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/toolsif which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi'
```

Comment: please show `.bash_profile` with line 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `.bash_profile` file is malformed at `sdk/toolsif which`. I reckon that should be `sdk/tools; if which` or simply add a linebreak after `tools` in front of the `if`.